# c++ cv::videoCapture give low fps for high resolution image and motion blur

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture

I want to get the stream of high-resolution images at 20 fps this is my code (https://gist.github.com/imrasp/7622ac73a05b567dd52b43ea3dd84879) for camera capture part. I create a separate thread to read frames and set size using [videoCapture setting](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a8c6d8c2d37505b5ca61ffd4bb54e9a7c) as follow

```
 stream1 >> matFrameForward;
 stream1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,  1280);
 stream1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720);
```

For this resolution, I got only 1 fps while an experiment on 640x480 gave 25fps. I also try with `stream1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 20);` but fps is not change. I use Mobius camera with the following setting:

- Webcam Mode: MJPG
- Audio Recording: Off
- Video Timestamp: Off
- Video Data Rate: Low
- Wide Dynamic Range: Low Light
- Field of View: Wide
- Video Resolution: 1280x720(720p)
- Video Frame Rate: 30 fps

Turn off audio and timestamp increase fps a bit (from 0.9 to 1.1). Currently, I am check fps by counting the number of receiving frame on 10 sec record time. **Is this method is ok for checking fps?** and **How to increase the fps using c++ and openCV 2.4.11**

I am also confronted with motion blur when moving the camera. as I research so far these cause from

- low light environment, the brighter scene will shorten exposure and
  improve the sharpness.
- high image resolution.
- [VideoCapture's settting](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a8c6d8c2d37505b5ca61ffd4bb54e9a7c)

**How to config VideoCapture setting for this problem and apart from the reason above is blur motion cause from the camera doesn't have autofocus or not.**

my grab frame function

```
void cameraLoop(){
    while (!time_to_exit) {
        timestampcamera_ns = boost::lexical_cast<uint64_t>(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count());

        pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutexFrameCam1Last);
        stream1 >> matFrameForward;
        stream1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,  1280);
        stream1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720);
        // stream1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 3);
        // stream1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 20);

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&_mutexFrameCam1Last);

        std::cout << "read matFrameForward size : " << matFrameForward.size() << std::endl;
        cv::imshow("Camera", matFrameForward);
        if (cv::waitKey(30) >= 0)
            break;
    }
}
```

The camera is declared as global variable and initialize in `initializeParams()`

```
void initializeParams(){
    stream1 = cv::VideoCapture(1);
    ... // other parameters
}
```

I create camera thread using boost thread declare in the main function.

```
std::cout << "Start camera thread..." << std::endl;
boost::thread threadCamera = boost::thread(&cameraLoop);
```

Comment: Please show your main image processing loop, where you acquire, and maybe process and maybe display your images.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you so much for your kindly help, I edit and add part of my code above.

Comment: I presume you have tried reducing the `waitKey()` to 1 instead of 30?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have tried reducing `waitKey()` and also disable display (remove `imshow()` and `waitKey()`. These still giving me the same fps.

Comment: Why do you set height and width on every iteration - normally you just set it once before entering the main  loop.

Comment: Thank you so much, finally, it works!

Comment: Cool, good luck with your project! Questions (and answers) are free, so come back and ask another question if you need a hand.